# Substitution - what's the technical name of the inference rule?

Tags: logic, terminology

Suppose the following are written down in some context.
$$3x^2 < y$$
$$x^2=xy-1$$

Then we may deduce (also within that context) that
$$3(xy-1) < y$$

What is the technical name of this inference rule?

Answer (score 6):

$$\text{Substitution}\quad\quad\quad$$

If $f(x,y) = g(x,y)$, then replacing any occurrence of $f(x,y)$ by $g(x,y)$ is replacing one equivalent expression, with another. One might think of this as employing the axioms of equality.

That is, it is not so much an "inference rule" as it is an *equality* or identity. It is using, within the context in which the identification between $\;x^2 = xy - 1\;$ is valid, Leibniz's law, "the principle of substitutivity".

$$\color{blue}{\bf x^2 = xy - 1} \iff \color{red}{\bf 3}\color{blue}{\bf x^2} = \color{red}{\bf 3}(\color{blue}{\bf xy - 1})$$

$$\color{red}{\bf 3}\color{blue}{\bf x^2} \lt y \iff \color{red}{\bf 3}(\color{blue}{\bf xy - 1}) \lt y$$

Comment: Well, I have another talk next week and need to put the finishing touches on it, plus two talks at work! I need a break from these, so will take a break - so I can clean my house! :-)